# Unity Playscape error during post-build on ios

Tags: ios, sdk, post-build, playscape

Using Playscape sdk and building to IOS gives me strange errors:

[image]

anyone had this errors?

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace your `PushNotificationsIOS.cs` with this [PushNotificationsIOS.cs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xo72zqhdjimnh53/PushNotificationsIOS.cs?dl=0)
2. In exported xcode project to do next:

   - Add dynamic lib: Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> `libstdc++6.0.9.dylib`
   - Add dynamic lib: Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> `libc++.dylib`